# Why doesn't my second YouTube embed display?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

My problem is simple.  I can display a single video just fine.  But embedding a second by creating a new instance of `YT.Player` has no effect.  It doesn't even crash or log any errors.

My code attempts to create a second embed by pretty much just copying and pasting the original embed code and appending `B` to all the variables associated with the second video.

I looked long and hard for any typos but haven't seen any after a couple checks, so I don't think that's the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <center><div id="player"></div></center>

    <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      var int;
      var int2;
      var int3;
      var tim;

      var playerB;
      var intB;
      var int2B;
      var int3B;
      var timB;

      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          origin: window.location.href,
          height: '400',
          width: '400',
          videoId: 'pRmChG3Jf_Q',
          events: {
            'onReady': seekRandom,
            'onStateChange': onStateChange
          }
        });
        playerB = new YT.Player('playerB', {
          origin: window.location.href,
          height: '400',
          width: '400',
          videoId: 'bsgXjiFM_Sc',
          events: {
            'onReady': seekRandomB,
            'onStateChange': onStateChangeB
          }
        });
      }
      function onStateChange(event) {
        switch (event.data) {
          case -1:
            player.playVideo();
            player.setVolume(0);
            break;
          case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
            player.setVolume(0);
            clearTimeout(tim);
            break;
          case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
            int3 = setInterval(function(){
              if (player.getPlayerState() != YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
                player.setVolume(player.getVolume() + 2.5);
              }
            }, 50)

            tim = setTimeout(function(){
              int2 = setInterval(function(){
                if (player.getPlayerState() != YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
                  player.setVolume(player.getVolume() - 2.5);
                }
              }, 50)
            }, 2500);
            break;
        }
      }

      function seekRandom(event) {
        int = setInterval(function(){
          seconds_buffered = player.getVideoLoadedFraction() *     player.getDuration();
          player.seekTo(Math.max(Math.random()*seconds_buffered - 5, 0), true);
          clearInterval(int2);
          clearInterval(int3);
        }, 5000);
      }

      function onStateChangeB(event) {
        switch (event.data) {
          case -1:
            playerB.playVideo();
            playerB.setVolume(0);
            break;
          case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
            playerB.setVolume(0);
            clearTimeout(timB);
            break;
          case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
            int3B = setInterval(function(){
              if (playerB.getPlayerState() != YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
                playerB.setVolume(playerB.getVolume() + 2);
              }
            }, 50)

            timB = setTimeout(function(){
              int2B = setInterval(function(){
                if (playerB.getPlayerState() != YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
                  playerB.setVolume(playerB.getVolume() - 2);
                }
              }, 50)
            }, 2500);
            break;
        }
      }

      function seekRandomB(event) {
        intB = setInterval(function(){
          seconds_buffered = playerB.getVideoLoadedFraction() * playerB.getDuration();
          playerB.seekTo(Math.max(Math.random()*seconds_buffered - 5, 0), true);
          clearInterval(int2B);
          clearInterval(int3B);
        }, 5000);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you open the F12 developer tools in your browser and look in the console window for warnings and errors?

Comment: Okay I turned off uBlock Origin and there are no errors at all now.  Not even a warning.  But my second video still won't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that I had to create a second `<div>` with an `id` of `playerB`.